# how to send POST request with Postman using Django 4 ?? faced with : "detail": "CSRF Failed: CSRF token missing."

Tags: python, django, request, postman, csrf

I faced with the problem. I write a simple test app. Now I want to use Postman to send a request. Everything is going ok if I send GET request I got all staff correctly. But if I try to send POST or PUT the error is "detail": "CSRF Failed: CSRF token missing." I logged in by admin. I took cookies from the session: sessionid and csrftoken but it did not work. In postman I tried copy CSRF token from headers. I used all this 3 tokens in fact. I tried usr each separately but all my attempts fold. What shall I do to send POST in Django 4 through Postman?????? I use here oauth with github
but the error appears in both cases: login with admin or oauth.
My code is below

settings.py
''''

```
"""
Django settings for books project.`enter code here`

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 4.0.3.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/settings/
"""

from pathlib import Path

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent

# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'django-insecure-ozz!^(_j!6gd5lc_f)&kyyo743l^g5r$sx!wg=9zd*)l7n'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []

# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',

    'social_django',

    'store',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'books.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': ['templates'],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]



REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_RENDERER_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.renderers.JSONRenderer',
    ),
    'DEFAULT_PARSER_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.parsers.JSONParser',
    ),
}

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'books.wsgi.application'

# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'books_db',
        'USER': 'books_user',
        'PASSWORD': '',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '',
    }
}

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    'social_core.backends.github.GithubOAuth2',
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
)

# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]

# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_TZ = True

# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = 'static/'



# Default primary key field type
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/settings/#default-auto-field

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'

SOCIAL_AUTH_JSONFIELD_ENABLED = True

SOCIAL_AUTH_GITHUB_KEY = 'e18b995bb43db2872f'
SOCIAL_AUTH_GITHUB_SECRET = '4cfb0b968b14a0f86491c5b3126550b72befe8'

CSRF_HEADER_NAME = 'LAPwVB8oVvcX4609bsaY3bi1SpiXBBpqZLnO84MBcsNtdjY7bboibRduwGDr'
```

urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import include
from django.urls import path
from rest_framework.routers import SimpleRouter
from store.views import auth
from store.views import BookViewSet

router = SimpleRouter()
router.register(r'book', BookViewSet)

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('social_django.urls', namespace='social')),
    path('auth/', auth)
]
urlpatterns += router.urls
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models


class Book(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=7, decimal_places=2)
    author_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    def __str__(self):
        return f'Id: {self.id}, name: {self.name}'
```

serializers.py

```
from rest_framework.serializers import ModelSerializer

from store.models import Book


class BooksSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Book
        fields = '__all__'
```

views.py

```
from django_filters.rest_framework import DjangoFilterBackend
from rest_framework.filters import SearchFilter, OrderingFilter
from rest_framework.permissions import IsAuthenticated
from rest_framework.viewsets import ModelViewSet
from django.shortcuts import render
from store.models import Book
from store.serializers import BooksSerializer


class BookViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Book.objects.all()
    serializer_class = BooksSerializer
    filter_backends = [DjangoFilterBackend, SearchFilter, OrderingFilter]
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]
    filter_fields = ['price']
    search_fields = ['name', 'author_name']
    ordering_fields = ['price', 'author_name']


def auth(request):
    return render(request, 'oauth.html')
```

''''

Comment: Do you have a {% csrf_token %} after your form in the template? Read here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/csrf/

Comment: well I don't have any form there. One template I have is for OAuth. I try to send request using pure request method POST in postman. Cause of it all tokens I got from session cookies.

Comment: I'm almost certain that you might need to use `CorsHeaders` from `pip install django-cors-headers` since this could be appropriated to an api call. In settings, enable `CORS_ALLOW_ALL_ORIGINS` to `True` and you should be able to accomplish your task.

Comment: I use PyCharm. There in preferences I added django-cors-headers. Than CORS_ALLOW_ALL_ORIGINS turned it to True. In Postman I wrote cookies -> sessionid=94ycbvu55ok2bf56vh7nm9edp8vm, cookies -> csrftoken=IPUTwLvQ5XU54LJkTvtCcJhIpnsaJ57S2KpU6wnF7xgWfQtiQT3Fd9CFG, X-CSRFToken -> 40I70gbNMkjBMXjVwZkRLa5MvMM5edg2B2d9kshfsCENVuuSvoYjWVnGOhH. After that I got the sane issue.